# css positioning drop down under parent

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list item in my navbar and can't get the dropdown section to align underneath the parent link. I am trying to use just css and know I've done it before, it's just stumping me at the moment. None of the other examples I've come across use the same menu format so it's been troubling trying to force fit pieces of code. Please help me with this easy solution

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="left">Home</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Link2</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Link3</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Link4
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubLink1</a></li><br />
                <li><a href="#">SubLink2</a></li><br />
                <li><a href="#">SubLink3</a></li><br />
                <li><a href="#">SubLink4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#navbar {
    width:75%;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
    top:218px;

}

#navbar li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
}

#navbar a {
    background-color:#862D59;
    font-size:18px;
    width:60px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px 15px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
#navbar a:hover {
    background-color:#602040;
    border-bottom:solid 4px #969;
}

#navbar li ul {
    display:none;
}

#navbar li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
}
```

**Working Example**
https://jsfiddle.net/o6Ldutp5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should use a reset css of some kind to remove the default margin / padding attached to `ul` & `li`.

Then *validate* your HTML, it contained a number of errors such as missing the opening `ul` etc.

Then it's just a matter of using `position:absolute` and appropriate values.

`top:100%` will place the menu directly below the `li` parent (with `position:relative`) *regardless* of the height of the `li`.

`left:0` will align the left edge of the submenu to the left side of the parent `li`.

```css
#navbar {
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: right;
}
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#navbar a {
  background-color: #862D59;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #602040;
  border-bottom: solid 4px #969;
}
#navbar li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#navbar li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="left">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4 </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubLink1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SubLink2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SubLink3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SubLink4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, works great! A few tweeks to yours and I had it back in the right positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I've written my own minimal CSS without the styling, try replacing your whole CSS with this -

I've also edited your HTML by removing the `comments` and `<br />` tags

```
div#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

div#navbar li ul {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 10px;
}

div#navbar li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}

div#navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul,ol,li {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o6Ldutp5/5/)