# CSS: Menu elements positioning

Tags: html, css

[image]

The picture above is the result of my html:

```
<div id='navi'>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>
            <a...>Item 5</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a...>Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a...>Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a...>Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a...>Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Link 1, 2 etc are menu elements, in this case of menu "Item 5". To make them be aligned vertically, the width of their < li >s is set to 100%. But because of that, all menu elements cover the whole space, beginning at the left edge. I need them to start under in this case "Item 5", or whatever menu the mouse is hovering over now. 
Could you please help?

Thanks.

CSS:

```
#navi ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 0 58px; }

#navi li {
float: left;
padding: 5px 6px 5px 10px;
height: 33px;
font-size: 20px;
background-position: right 18px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden; /* if text-resize, this'll keep the nav the same size */}

#navi li:last-child {
background-image: none;
} 

#navi li a {
display: block;
line-height: 24px;
overflow: hidden;       
color: #002665;}

#navi li:hover {
background:black;
}

#navi li ul {
display:none;
}

#navi li:hover ul {
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0px;
width:100%;
color:white;
}
#navi li ul li {
position:relative;
width:100%;
padding:15px 0px;
background:black;
text-indent:10px;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "helveticaregular","HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
z-index: 1;
}

#navi li ul li img:hover,#navi li ul a:hover li img{
border-bottom:1px white solid;
margin-bottom:-1px;
}
#navi li ul li:hover {
background:black;
text-decoration:underline;
}
#navi ul li a{
color:#F5F5F5;
background-color: transparent;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Helvetica, "helveticaregular","HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
}
```

Comment: You can add a jsfiddle

Comment: This answer might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364275/css-positioning-drop-down-under-parent/31365672#31365672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to make a drop down menu?
What you need to do is set the second level ul position to absolute.

```
ul li ul {
     position: absolute;
}
```

The parent container will need its position set to `relative`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. When I set position of the li (container) to relative, the menu elements just did not show up.

Comment: possibly because absolute positioned item with no height or width will be 0, or they are underneath another z-index element.  open your html in chrome dev tools, select the element in html, and see the size of the container, im guessing either width or height is 0 pixels

Comment: No, there is width of the containing li, and width of the ul is auto, and changing it to e.g. 100px also doesn't help...

Comment: I found what caused the problem: 
overflow: hidden;
on #navi li

Answer (score -1):

Could you make the upper level div like so? That might help.
`<li><div>Item mark up here.</div></li>`